# getting empty app.js file after running npm run dev

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm

i'm using laravel 7.0 on windows 10. I'm following freecodecamp tutorial on youtube for laravel.
when i run npm run dev i got errors i updated npm by using this command "npm install npm@latest" and everything working fine and i ran npm run dev and i got no errors. but in resources folder and further in js folder i got nothing but "require('./bootstrap');" only and also in sass folder i did not get variable.scss file but in tutorial he have all things good like in app.js file it has vue.js content.